# What are the Best Practices regarding error codes returned by a Console application?

Tags: c#, console-application, dos

In c# you can return an integer to the underlying caller using Environment.Exit(n) (which can be tested, for instance, using the ERRORLEVEL variable from a DOS script).

Are there best practices regarding those codes?

I think 0 = no error... but are there numbers reserved? Can I use negative numbers? etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zero usually means that there were no errors. As for others, I don't think there is a reserved set. I would usually define what the different return codes of my application meant and document them.

DOS only handles a maximum of 256 possible return codes, but in reality I doubt you would ever use/need that many.

You can use negative values, but note that negative values do not necessarily mean anything different from positive values.

Answer (score 3):

The most extensive use of return codes I've seen is in Robocopy.  It may provide guidance for other apps.  Robocopy uses return codes as flags:

> 0×10 Serious error. Robocopy did not
>   copy any files. This is either a usage
>   error or an error due to insufficient
>   access privileges on the source or
>   destination directories.
>
> 0×08 Some files or directories could
>   not be copied (copy errors occurred
>   and the retry limit was exceeded).
>   Check these errors further.
>
> 0×04 Some Mismatched files or
>   directories were detected. Examine the
>   output log. Housekeeping is probably
>   necessary.
>
> 0×02 Some Extra files or directories
>   were detected. Examine the output log.
>   Some housekeeping may be needed.
>
> 0×01 One or more files were copied
>   successfully (that is, new files have
>   arrived).
>
> 0×00 No errors occurred, and no
>   copying was done. The source and
>   destination directory trees are
>   completely synchronized.